# python re - regular expression capture data from string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like below

\nThis lists the capacity of all currently mounted filesystems.\nCommand:\nFile-System\nMbytes\nUsed\nAvail %Used Mounted on\n/dev/vg00/lvol3\n21.0g\n312\n20.5g\n2% /\n/dev/vg00/lvol1\n2097\n511\n1573\n25% /stand\n/dev/vg00/lvol8\n41.9g\n7225\n34.4g\n17% /var\n/dev/vg00/lvol7\n21.0g\n13.9g\n6982\n67% /usr\n/dev/vgxyz/lvusr_xyz\n21.0g\n1558\n18.2g\n8% /usr/abc\n/dev/vg00/lvol6\n21.0g\n5472\n15.4g\n26% /tmp\n

I need to capture the fields as below:

File-System     Mbytes Used Avail %Used Mounted_on

/dev/vg00/lvol3 21.0g 312 20.5g 2% /

/dev/vg00/lvol1 2097 511 1573 25% /stand

Please help
I tried the following

rx_sequence = re.compile(r"^.*?\n(/dev/.*?)\n(\d{1,}.*?)\n(\d+?)\n(\d{1,}.+?)\n(\d{1,}%)\s(.*?)",re.DOTALL)

for match in rx_sequence.finditer(str1):
    print match.group(1)

/dev/vg00/lvol3

It only print the first match.

Comment: Your question is? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service

Answer (score 0):

You could split the data up as follows:

```
data = """\nThis lists the capacity of all currently mounted filesystems.\nCommand:\nFile-System\nMbytes\nUsed\nAvail %Used Mounted on\n/dev/vg00/lvol3\n21.0g\n312\n20.5g\n2% /\n/dev/vg00/lvol1\n2097\n511\n1573\n25% /stand\n/dev/vg00/lvol8\n41.9g\n7225\n34.4g\n17% /var\n/dev/vg00/lvol7\n21.0g\n13.9g\n6982\n67% /usr\n/dev/vgxyz/lvusr_xyz\n21.0g\n1558\n18.2g\n8% /usr/abc\n/dev/vg00/lvol6\n21.0g\n5472\n15.4g\n26% /tmp\n"""

lines = data.splitlines()[7:]
entries = [entry for entry in zip(*([iter(lines)] * 5))]

for entry in entries:
    print entry
```

This would give you a list of tuple entries displayed as follows:

```
('/dev/vg00/lvol3', '21.0g', '312', '20.5g', '2% /')
('/dev/vg00/lvol1', '2097', '511', '1573', '25% /stand')
('/dev/vg00/lvol8', '41.9g', '7225', '34.4g', '17% /var')
('/dev/vg00/lvol7', '21.0g', '13.9g', '6982', '67% /usr')
('/dev/vgxyz/lvusr_xyz', '21.0g', '1558', '18.2g', '8% /usr/abc')
('/dev/vg00/lvol6', '21.0g', '5472', '15.4g', '26% /tmp')
```

It works by first splitting the data into lines and skipping over the first few lines. It then reads 5 lines at a time to create a tuple for each entry. A regular expression would be overkill as all of your entries are already delimited using newlines.

Comment: The below seems to be doing what I want. Thanks all  


rx_sequence = re.compile(r"^.*?(/dev/.*?)\n(\d{1,}.*?)\n(\d+?)\n(\d{1,}.+?)\n(\d{1,}%)\s(.*?)$",re.MULTILINE)